# On Linux: how can I programmatically determine if a NIC interface is enabled and plugged in?

Tags: linux, network-programming

I want to determine if a network card is enabled, up, and plugged in. Basically, I want to know if the network card will work. I need this information from with a C++ program, and would like to display an error message when the network isn't working properly. If possible I would like to avoid using shell commands to determine this information.

Comment: if you just want to determine if the NIC is "up" use `ioctl()` with `SIOCGIFFLAGS` to directly get the boolean status see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723061/how-to-check-if-interface-is-up

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can look at `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` where eth0 is your interface to see if it's up.

Look at `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` to see if there is a carrier.

Though I guess executing `ifconfig` and friends will give you more compatibility to *BSDs.

Comment: Is there something similarly elegant for older kernels?  On my old CentOS 4 box, with kernel 2.6.9, I have no "operstate" file under /sys/class/net/eth?.

Comment: Do you know how to check the link status?  Is there a file for that?  As in when you do `ethtool eth0`, output will show you link detected:  YES

Comment: @EFraim I've just verified that this is not working correctly on my 2.6.31. It seems that for an access point it will not be up until someone is not connected, while ifconfig shows it's up. That is a very big distinction. I can't easily check this right now with new kernel though. In other words flag shows up, carrier 0, operstate down.

Answer (score 6):

1. open `AF_NETLINK` socket
2. bind it to `sockaddr_nl` with `nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK`
3. send message `RTM_GETLINK` to kernel
4. make poll/epoll on socket to read `RTM_NEWLINK` and `RTM_DELLINK` messages
5. you will receive initial interfaces list and its changes in future

Answer (score 4):

Remember, on Linux "everything" is a file.

The best way would be to use the approved kernel<->userspace communication, namely `sysfs`, mounted at `/sys`. Network devices are linked at `/sys/class/net`

If you wish to use the `ioctl` interface, look at `man netdevice`

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to identify the network card? You might try taking a look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` which maps hardware MAC addresses into nice names (like eth0).

Then, when you have the nicer name, you can run things like `ethtool eth0` to determine if it is [physically] connected (last line), `ifconfig eth0` to determine if it is up (look for "UP BROADCAST..."), and if it has an IP address.

I'm willing to guess there are automatic libraries for this though; have you looked around? I'm not sure if there's easily accessible code in NetworkManager, but that should be a good first place to look.

Answer (score 1):

Run through the output of [`getifaddrs`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html), you can use the link layer for the MAC address to identify an adapter and check the `ifa_flags` for IFF_UP.  Use [`AF_NETLINK`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/netlink.7.html) for notifications about interface changes.