# How to check if interface is up

Tags: c++, linux, ioctl

Title pretty much says it all. If I run `ifconfig`, I get this:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet -snip-  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast -snip-
    ...
```

Using this, I can know if it's up or not (`<UP,...`), but I want to be able to do this in C (or C++, if there is a simpler solution there) without relying on parsing external processes.

---

Here is what I've got so far (doesn't work):

```
bool is_interface_online(std::string interface) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface.c_str());
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
            perror("SIOCGIFFLAGS");
    }
    close(sock);
    return !!(ifr.ifr_flags | IFF_UP);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction for this?

Comment: ifconfig is open source btw

Comment: This fails if your interface does not use IPv6.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answer was simple: I used the bitwise OR (`|`) operator instead of the AND (`&`) operator. Fixed code is:

```
bool is_interface_online(std::string interface) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface.c_str());
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
            perror("SIOCGIFFLAGS");
    }
    close(sock);
    return !!(ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_UP);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you care about the up/down state of the interface you might want to use the "IFF_RUNNING" flag instead of the "IFF_UP" flag provided by the current answer.

Comment: Can I use the same in virtual environment? How can I set interface down in virtual environment? I am running test program which checks IFF_RUNNING flag at every 500 milliseconds. I am not receiving interface down, it always finds IFF_RUNNING flag set. Need help in this matter.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the `strace` command to see how `ifconfig` works? you can even see what parameters are passed to functions and other interesting details of how `ifconfig` works ..

Comment: Yes I have, in fact, that's what I used to write the function :D

Comment: I know this is an extremely old post, but what's the purpose of the `!!` in the return statement? I'm not aware of a `!!` operator, so is this simply "not not"? If so, then the `!!` can be removed.

Comment: a little late answer but the purpose of two `!!` is simple. It's use to return 0 or 1 from large return exit code. Exemple `!! 0` will return 0 because `!0 = 1` and `!1 = 0`.
But for any other values `n != 0`, it will return `1`. Exemple with `!!10`:  `!10 = 0` and `!0 = 1`