# How to check if a network adapter is present in C++ (windows)

Tags: c++, networking, winsock, winsock2

I need to check periodically if an network adapter is present under windows, I tried with `GetInterfaceInfo` but it doesn't return the "name" like "Local area connection 1" (that I need) but a long ID.
I also find that code ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723061/how-to-check-if-interface-is-up)):

```
bool is_interface_online(std::string interface) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface.c_str());
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
            perror("SIOCGIFFLAGS");
    }
    close(sock);
    return !!(ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_UP);
}
```

But I can't port it to work on windows.

I also have a perfect command:

```
wmic NIC get NetConnectionID
```

But in c++ it seems that I need to write to a file first to read the result of the command (with `ShellExecute`), and as I will check maybe every second, I want to avoid disk operations.

Comment: Use `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddress()` to enumerate available adapters. Names are one of the (many) fields provided.

Comment: I don't get the "Name" I set myself in windows but I will do with it, thanks.

Comment: [`IP_ADAPTER_INFO::AdapterName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_info) and [`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES::AdapterName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh)

Comment: No, them give a kind of guid, but after having tried GetAdaptersAddresses I saw that there's a FriendlyName variable, and this is it !